# React Material UI table update all rows height according to largest height of cell

Tags: react-hooks, material-ui

Goal: I need to update the height of all rows according to the tallest cell between two tables.

I have created two tables that exist side by side that *both* look like so:

```
<Table aria-label="simple table">
  <TableHead>
    <TableRow>
       {actualColumn.length && actualColumn.map(col => (
         <TableCell>{col.feature.label}</TableCell>
         ))}
    </TableRow>
  </TableHead>
  <TableBody>
  {
    rows.length && rows.map((cells, i) => (<TableRow sx={{
        '&:nth-of-type(odd)': { backgroundColor: '#F8FBFE', },
        '&:nth-of-type(even)': { backgroundColor: '#ECF1F6', },
    }} key={i}>
        {cells.map((cell) => {
            const value = getCellValue(cell);
            return (
                <TableCell ref={cellRef} >
                    {value !== "" && <div>{value}</div>}
                </TableCell>
            )
        })}
    </TableRow>))
}
  </TableBody>
</Table>
```

I tried to pass in as you can see a `cellRef` to access the the specific cell, and then inside `useCallback` to update the style of the cell height.

```
    const [rowHeight, setRowHeight] = useState(0);

    const rowRef = useCallback(node => {
        if (node !== null) {
            const rh = node.offsetHeight;
            if (rowHeight < rh) {
                setRowHeight(rh);
            }
            node.style.height = `${rowHeight}px`;
        }
    }, []);
```

Is there a different approach that i should be taking? Clearly this is not working but perhaps im on the right path.

Comment: Try to add `sx={{height:'max-content'}}` to your `TableCell` component: `<TableCell sx={{height:'max-content'}}>`

Comment: This wouldnt match the height between both tables however, right?

Comment: Chances are.
It'd be easier to help with a live demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to have been easier than i thought.

I set the `rowHeight` as part of the state, and then used that to give height to both of the tables body. Then i also added a ref on the table body itself, and styled each row with `height: 'inherit'`
Code looks like so:

```
   const [rowHeight, setRowHeight] = useState(0);

    const rowRef = useCallback(node => {
        if (node !== null) {
            [...node.childNodes].forEach(({ offsetHeight = 0 }) => {
                if(rowHeight < offsetHeight) {
                    setRowHeight(() => offsetHeight)
                }
            })
        }
    }, [rowHeight]);
```